# ¿Como restar 1 día al valor que retorna datetime.today() en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Estoy usando la funcion today() del objeto datetime para obtener la fecha actual, si quiero restarle un dia para tener la fecha del dia anterior no me deja:}

```
today=datetime.today()-1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

Existe otra función para restar o añadir días?

Comment: Debes usar  `today - datetime.timedelta(1)` (en tu caso).

Comment: Me aparece el error: today=datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar o restar usando la clase datetime, necesitas tambien importar timedelta de datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
today=datetime.today()+timedelta(days=-1)
```

Te dejo algunos ejemplos aca:

SUMAR 60 SEGUNDOS

```
today=datetime.today()+timedelta(seconds=60)
```

RESTAR 15 MINUTOS:

```
today=datetime.today()-timedelta(minutes=15)
```

Espero sea de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

para restar en día al valor que retorna *datetime.today()* puedes usar *timedelta*

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
hoy = datetime.today() # 2019-10-17
ayer = hoy - timedelta(days=1)
ayer.date() # 2019-10-16
```